# Dropdown selection in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML code:

```
 <div class="dropdown-datepicker ng-scope" ng-class="{invalid : !o[typeOfDate].valid && formData[typeOfDate], valid : o[typeOfDate].valid}" label-since-month="Seit Monat" label-since-year="Seit Jahr" month-placeholder="Monat" year-placeholder="Jahr" label-datepicker=" seit" date="employedSince" tooltip="Bitte geben Sie hier den Monat und das Jahr an, seit dem Sie in dem Unternehmen beschäftigt sind" set-tabindex="0" r-dropdown-datepicker="">

 <p class="dropdown-date-label bold italic ng-binding"> seit</p>
 <div class="custom-select white month"> 

 <span class="chevron-thin-down">-</span> 
   <select class="special-valid ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-blur="isSlideValid(slider.index)" ng-model="o[typeOfDate].month" name="years" tabindex="0">
        <option class="ng-binding" style="display: none;" selected="" disabled="" value="">Monat</option> 
       <option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].month == $index+1" value="1" ng-repeat="m in monthsDrop">Januar</option>
</select>

 <div class="custom-select white year">
  <select class="special-valid ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-blur="isSlideValid(slider.index)" ng-model="o[typeOfDate].year" name="years" tabindex="0"> 
        <option class="ng-binding" style="display: none;" selected="" disabled="" value="">Jahr</option>
        <option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].year == y" value="2015" ng-repeat="y in yearsDrop">2015</option>
        <option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].year == y" value="2014" ng-repeat="y in yearsDrop">2014</option>

  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am facing some issues with the drop down selections.I've tried the following but it's not working

```
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='years'])[3]"))).selectByVis‌​ibleText("Mai");
```

Please help me

Comment: <select class="special-valid ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" tabindex="0" name="years" ng-model="o[typeOfDate].month" ng-blur="isSlideValid(slider.index)">

Comment: I tried this , but not working new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='years'])[3]"))).selectByVisibleText("Mai");

Comment: Edit your question and add the code into that instead of the comment.

Comment: Not working means is it firing any exception?

Comment: Here is [3] represents index of select tag or what?? Why did you mention index in xpath..?

Comment: I copied the xpath from selenium IDE. Actually the field contains both Year & Month both of them having the same name

Comment: I think you have multiple `select` dropdowns with attribute `years`. And, the one you are concerned about is the 3rd one in the chronological order. Am I correct @Prasanth ? Also, please add a screenshot of the dropdown you are trying to automate by [uploading the same in imgur](http://imgur.com/) and adding link here (as you don't have sufficient privilege, as of now, to add screenshot directly here)

Comment: @subh  http://i.imgur.com/VN3Veg4.png?1

Comment: Doesn't seem like a normal select dropdown to me. Are you sure the xpath you are inputting is referring to this particular dropdown, I mean when you are inspecting the element using [Firepath extension of Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/firepath/), it is showing the above xpath ? Also, can you please add the html code for the complete set including the `select` tag and its `options`.

Comment: Can you post your URL...or full html code??

Comment: <div class="dropdown-datepicker ng-scope" ng-class="{invalid : !o[typeOfDate].valid && formData[typeOfDate], valid : o[typeOfDate].valid}" label-since-month="Seit Monat" label-since-year="Seit Jahr" month-placeholder="Monat" year-placeholder="Jahr" label-datepicker=" seit" date="employedSince" tooltip="Bitte geben Sie hier den Monat und das Jahr an, seit dem Sie in dem Unternehmen beschäftigt sind" set-tabindex="0" r-dropdown-datepicker="">

Comment: <p class="dropdown-date-label bold italic ng-binding"> seit</p>
<div class="custom-select white month">
<span class="chevron-thin-down">-</span>
<select class="special-valid ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-blur="isSlideValid(slider.index)" ng-model="o[typeOfDate].month" name="years" tabindex="0">
<option class="ng-binding" style="display: none;" selected="" disabled="" value="">Monat</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].month == $index+1" value="1" ng-repeat="m in monthsDrop">Januar</option>

Comment: <div class="custom-select white year">
<select class="special-valid ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-blur="isSlideValid(slider.index)" ng-model="o[typeOfDate].year" name="years" tabindex="0">
<option class="ng-binding" style="display: none;" selected="" disabled="" value="">Jahr</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].year == y" value="2015" ng-repeat="y in yearsDrop">2015</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-selected="o[typeOfDate].year == y" value="2014" ng-repeat="y in yearsDrop">2014</option>

Comment: Edit your question and post this code in your question..

Comment: You can write xpath using className instead of using name. class name for two select tag is different na..so you can use className. like **//select[@class='special-valid ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope'].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    WebElement webElement = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//select[@class='special-valid ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched']"));

    Select select = new Select(webElement);
    select.selectByVisibleText("Monat");
```

You can also use ,

```
    select.selectByIndex(1);
```

instead of

```
    select.selectByVisibleText();
```

Comment: @ saritha , its saying as "no such element"

Comment: I think you did not post your complete code..Can you post your URL?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the option, you need to click the drop down first. This will enable the options to be displayed. Also observe that options have a property named `disabled`, for which selection can not be done.

Try below code (C#), can be converted to equivalent Java code...

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='years'])[3]")); // Assuming you have proper indexing.
element.Click();
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[@name='years'])[3]")));
select.SelectByText("Januar"); // Monar option diabled.
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssSelector for compound class names. Just add a decimal point at the beggining of the name and replace all "spaces" with a decimal point too. The following was tested and in working condition.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ng-pristine.ng-valid.needsclick.ng-empty.ng-touched"))).selectByVisibleText(reason1);
```